# Analyzing string input until it reaches a certain element in python

Tags: python

I would like to print this till it reaches the fifth bar ("/")...:

- example/cc/pk///jdjuedmcke/hello/

...to get this output:

- example/cc/pk///

I don't know if I've made myself clear:

- example/ : first bar
- cc/ : second one
- pk/// : third,fourth and fifth ones

Thanks for answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to accomplish this, I would use something like this though

```py
str1 = "example/cc/pk///jdjuedmcke/hello/"
result = '/'.join(str1.split('/')[:5]) + '/'
```

Which returns `example/cc/pk///`

Answer (score 0):

This will work. Just need to iterate over the string

```
string="example/cc/pk///jdjuedmcke/hello/"
find_what="/"
number=0
new_list=[]
string=[x for x in string]
for i in string:
    if number==5:
        print(''.join(new_list))
        break
    elif i==find_what:
        number+=1
        new_list.append(i)
    else:
        new_list.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

use regular expression:

```python
import re

str1 = "example/cc/pk///jdjuedmcke/hello/"
result = re.sub(r'^(([^/]*/){5}).*', r'\1', str1)
# or
result = re.sub(r'^((.*?/){5}).*', r'\1', str1)
```